# How to order the position of mongodb documents based on the position of items on a list. (meteor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

```
    Template.orionMaterializePagesIndex.rendered = function(){
        $(".table").sortable({
           items: ".odd,.even",
           delay: 100,
           refreshPositions: true,
           revert: true,
           helper: "clone",
           scroll: true,
           scrollSensitivity: 50,
           scrollSpeed: 35,
           start: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).addClass("dragging");
           }, // end of start
           stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.item).removeClass("dragging");
           }, // end of stop
           update: function(event, ui) {
            var index = 0;


            _.each($(".odd,.even"), function(item) {
              orion.pages.collection.update({_id: item.id}, {
                $set:{
                  pos: index++,
                }
              });
            });
          } 
        }).disableSelection();
    }
```

Here's also an image of my monogodb collection documents to the fields that are generated->
http://s12.postimg.org/wp0c82yjx/Screen_Shot_2015_06_28_at_11_34_33_AM.png

Answer (score 0):

You could add a field "listPosition" to each document in your collection. You could sort the collection of documents by listPosition, and update the listPosition for each document as necessary.

```
Collection.find({}, {sort: {listPosition: 1}});
```

The above code will return the ordered documents.

Comment: So I added a listPosition field. But each time I insert a new document the listPosition value will always be 1. 
check out the gist
https://gist.github.com/ecuanaso/ec4090f3bb3740b8cda3

Comment: @ecuanaso This function will always return 1 on an insert. This is okay if you are inserting to the beginning of the list, but you must update the listPosition of all other documents in the collection.

Comment: So I have to update the other listPositions of all my other documents? Ok, could you provide an example of how to do this. I have a working knowledge of javascript.